# What does the "base" syntax mean?

Tags: c#, syntax

Can somone please tell me what does the syntax below means?

```
public ScopeCanvas(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
{
}
```

I mean what is `method(argument) : base(argument) {}` ??

P.S This is a constructor of a class.

Comment: That's a constuctor, not a method.

Comment: I believe that if a question has more than 5 answers in less than two minutes, it shouldn't have been asked. @Sean87 you could easily google "C# base keyword"

Comment: [Google would give you much faster answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+base&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) then StackOverflow. (@Yorye Nathan - exactly my point.)

Comment: I know this is old, but I did google 'C# :base keyword' and got here... Of course the MSDN link was first, but SO answers are usually more succinct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `:base` syntax is a way for a derived type to chain to a constructor on the base class which accepts the specified argument.  If omitted the compiler will silently attempt to bind to a base class constructor which accepts 0 arguments.

```
class Parent {
  protected Parent(int id) { } 
}

class Child1 : Parent {
  internal Child1() { 
    // Doesn't compile.  Parent doesn't have a parameterless constructor and 
    // hence the implicit :base() won't work
  }
}

class Child2 : Parent {
  internal Child2() : base(42) { 
    // Works great
  }
}
```

There is also the `:this` syntax which allows chaining to constructors in the same type with a specified argument list

Comment: **"If omitted the compiler will silently attempt to bind to a base class constructor which accepts 0 arguments."** This is the most critical part of the explanation - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your class is likely defined like this:

```
MyClass : BaseClass
```

It derives from some other class.  `: base(...)` on your constructor calls the appropriate constructor in the base class before running the code in your derived class's constructor.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-base-constructor-in-c-sharp)'s a related question.

**EDIT**

As noted by **Tilak**, the [MSDN documentation on the **base** keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) provides a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

to call named constructor of base class. if base( argument ) is not specified, parameterless constructor is called

[What really is the purpose of "base" keyword in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644316/what-really-is-the-purpose-of-base-keyword-in-c)

[Base keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It calls the constructor from the base class passing the arguments `context` and `attrs`

Answer (score 2):

This is an abstract overloaded class constructor which allows for initilizing of arguments for the derived and the base class and specifying if an overloaded constructor is to be used.
[LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx)

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    { }
    public A(int size)
    { }
};

class B : public A
{
    public B() 
    {// this calls base class constructor A() 
    }
    public B(int size) : base(size)
    { // this calls the overloaded constructor A(size)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You class is inheriting from a baseclass, and when you intialize an object of type ScopeCanvas, the base constructor is called with a parameter list of (context, attrs)

Answer (score 1):

This means that this constructor takes two arguments, and passes them to the inherited objects constructor.  An example below with only one argument.

```
Public class BaseType
{
    public BaseType(object something)
    {

    }
}

public class MyType : BaseType
{
     public MyType(object context) : base(context)
     {

     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In above examples all are talking about **:base** no one is taking about **base.**
Yes base is uses to access member of parent but is not limited with constructor only we can use base._parentVariable or base._parentMethod() directly.

[base. example](http://www.asptricks.net/2015/07/what-is-base-keyword-in-c.html)