# Meaning of extending a class with " : base(typeof(classname))" (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have read this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base.

but I still don't understand what this line means.

```
public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string role) : base(typeof(CustomAuthorize))
```

CustomAuthorize is a class that extends `IAuthorizationFilter`.

what does `base(typeof(CustomAuthorize))` mean?

Is it trying to call the constructor of the `IAuthorizationFilter`?  why is it using `typeof` ?

The full class is:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
 {
        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string role) : base(typeof(CustomAuthorize))
       {
            Arguments = new object[] { role };
       }
 }

public class CustomAuthorize : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly string role;

        public CustomAuthorize(string role)
        {
            this.role = role;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
         Some code
```

The question differs from other similar questions as i want to know specifically what "base(typeof(CustomAuthorize))" means.

Comment: Interfaces cannot have constructors. Only structs and classes can have constructors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "base" syntax mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503255/what-does-the-base-syntax-mean)

Comment: What's the signature of your class? What class or struct does it inherit? Yes it might also _implement_ an interface, but you can only call `base` for the inherited type.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: `typeof` returns a `Type`, but your base class's constructor wants a `string`. Did you mean to use `typeof().Name`, or `nameof`? What actual information do you want passed to the base class's constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[base(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base) is used to call a member of your base class. In this case, it seems like you are calling the constructor of the class you inherit from.

[typeof(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast) returns the [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-6.0) of a defined type.

To sum it up, the command

```
public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string role) : base(typeof(CustomAuthorize))
```

calls the constructor of the class, `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` inherits from by passing the parameter `typeof(CustomAuthorize)`. This passed type then may be used to instanciate it for usage later on in the base class.

Comment: Ok but then can't you just use ": base(IAuthorizationFilter)" instead ?

Comment: No, because ```typeof(CustomAuthorize)``` is not the same like ```IAuthorizationFilter```

Comment: I'm confused tbh. Also this "calls the constructor of the class, CustomAuthorizeAttribute inherits from by passing the parameter typeof(CustomAuthorize). This passed type then may be used to instanciate it for usage later on in the base class." 

was a bit confusing .. can it be rephrased? im sorry

Comment: Not really ... You need to think step by step here. Check also the constructor of your base class to understand it. Maybe just ignore the last sentence.