# Advantage of calling a method using base pointer

Tags: c#

I have implemented a method in the base class as following:

```
  class A
    {
        protected void f1()
        {

        }
    }
    class A1 : A
    {
        public void f2()
        {
           //Simple Calling
            f1();
           //Calling using base pointer
            base.f1();
        }

    }
```

What is the difference between the calling simply and calling using a base pointer ? What are the advantages of either of the ways?

Comment: Quick tip - pointers do not exist in C# by default (unless you use unsafe code), you're basically using the `base` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

In your example there is no difference. However, consider situation when `f1` is virtual and  it has another implementation in `A1` class:

```
class A
{
    protected virtual void f1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

class A1 : A
{
    public void f2()
    {
       //Simple Calling - prints `A1`
        f1();
       //Calling using base pointer - prints `A`
        base.f1();
    }

    protected override void f1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A1");
    }
}
```

`f1()` is different than `base.f1()` then. The same situation appears when you use `new` keyword to hide base implementation within derived class:

```
protected new void f1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("A1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, none. But imagine this:

```
class A 
{ 
    public virtual void F() 
    {
    } 
}
class B : A 
{ 
   public override void F() 
   { 
       Console.WriteLine("B"); 
   } 
   public void F2() 
   { 
       F(); /*output: B*/ 
       base.F() /*no output*/ 
   } 
}
```

That's where `base` starts to come in useful.

Comment: Shouldn't `F` be marked as `override` instead of `virtual` in `B` class?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yes, my fault.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `this.f1()` (or simply `f1()`) and `base.f1()` becomes relevant when you override a virtual method:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void F()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void F()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }

    void Test()
    {
        F(); // Prints "B"
        this.F(); // Prints "B"
        base.F(); // Prints "A"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's only useful if you have overloaded/shadowed a method defined in the base class.

```
class A1 : A
{
    public void f2()
    {
       //Simple Calling
        f1();
       //Calling using base pointer
        base.f1();
    }

    protected new void f1()
    {
        // I won't be called
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also useful when you want to extend the functionality of a base method, but don't want to replicate it:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void F()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

    class B : A
    {
        public override void F()
        {
            base.F();
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }

        void Test()
        {
            F(); // Prints "A B"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The base keyword is used to refer to the base class when chaining constructors or when you want to access a member (method, property, anything) in the base class that has been overridden or hidden in the current class.
For example,

```
class A {
    protected virtual void Foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm A");
    }
}

class B : A {
    protected override void Foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm B");
    }

    public void Bar() {
        Foo();
        base.Foo();
    }
}
```

With these definitions,

```
new B().Bar();
```

would output

```
I'm B
I'm A
```

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644316/what-really-is-the-purpose-of-base-keyword-in-c)**

Answer (score 0):

if you override f1, base its needed to differentiate between them.

```
class A
{
    protected virtual void f1() {   }
}
class A1 : A
{
    protected override void f1() {   }

    public void f2()
    {
       //Simple Calling
        f1();                 <--- this will call to overrided f1 in this class
       //Calling using base pointer
        base.f1();
    }

}
```